# How to prefix a value before a randomly generated value in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I want to add a prefix for Ex:"65" before a randomly generated value between the given range in Groovy.

This is code without prefix:

`value.put('code',(RandomUtils.nextInt(100000, 2000000) as String))`

This is code with 65 prefix and is not working:

`value.put('code','65' + (RandomUtils.nextInt(100000, 2000000) as String))`

Comment: It seems that this code must works, what do u mean not working? can u share your result or the error?

Comment: Try `value.put("code", "65" << (RandomUtils.nextInt(100000, 2000000) as String))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with your snippets, both work just fine.

Just make sure to:

1. Add the necessary [import](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_imports) statement
2. Declare the `value` variable of the necessary type, i.e. a [Map](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html)

Example code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils

def value = [:]

value.put('code',(RandomUtils.nextInt(100000, 2000000) as String))

log.info('Without prefix: ' + value.get('code'))

value.put('code','65' + (RandomUtils.nextInt(100000, 2000000) as String))

log.info('With prefix: ' + value.get('code'))
```

and demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

If you want to generate a number of fixed length with a fixed prefix - take a look at [DecimalFormat class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)